# Qgis plugin: Qgis2threejs - 3D Object size/scale incorrect?

Tags: qgis, 3d, qgis2threejs

I've created a 3d map with objects (speheres, ashlar/extruded and cylinders) with Qgis2threejs. I noticed that the objects don't seem to fit in size. The sphere and the ashlar/extruded (made from polygon) should have the same height (meaning the object height), but they don't. The ashlar definitely looks higher/bigger than the sphere although they should have the same height/size.

A bit weird is that a few days ago both objects seemed to have the same height if I remember correctly.

I have read somewhere that the scale/size of 3d objects created with Qgis2threejs are not shown correctly. Is that correct?

Is there any way to solve this issue within Qgis2threejs?

Could the value for vertical exaggeration do something? It is currently on 1.5 default value. Playing with the value so far hasn't brought any improvement.

Edit: So below are my settings for the objects.

[image: Cylinder settings]

[image: Sphere settings]

[image: Ashlar settings]

[image: DEM settings]

[image: World settings]

Currently it looks like this:

[image: 3D look]

So my problem is that the red ashlar should start with its bottom at height 87 and be from there on 156 high. The sphere should be also up to 156 high (2 x 78), it should just fit in the ashlar. but in the 3d view it doesn't look like this.

Edit2: Used 156 for the sphere assuming that radius is not radius, but diameter.
[image]

Comment: Could you share your settings for each object, how you want it to look like and how it looks like? Right now it is hard to tell what might go wrong.

Comment: Thanks.. I've added screenshots of my settings in the original question.

Comment: Could it be that radius and diameter are mixed up in Qgis2threejs? Try radius of 156, does that work?

Comment: Thanks! At least it looks better now (see Edit 2 in original question).  The sphere is a bit above and below the ashlar, but this could just be a rendering issue(?). At least the relation sphere (156 diameter) and cylinder (165 height) seem to be correct, so this would hint that radius is actually diameter in Qgis2threejs. I also thought about it for a second, but didn't test it. What do you think, could this really be the issue here?

Comment: I posted an issue at the project's repo: https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs/issues/82
So the "global" vertical exaggeration might be the confusion here.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried to set vertical exaggeration to 1, but it doesn't look quite right. So far I think that assuming the spheres' and cylinders' value is diameter (not radius) appeared more accurate in the 3D view. Or does it maybe have something to do with the DEM or is it just a rendering issue?

Comment: +1 having the same problem over here. I'm projecting a _totally_ round shape which qgis2threejs turns into an egg-looking thing.